# Does $\limsup_{x\to\infty}\int_x^{x+h}f'(y)dy = 0$, $\forall h>0$, imply $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_x^{x+h}f'(y)dy = 0$, $\forall h>0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I have an absolutely continuous function $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ that satisfies $\limsup_{x\to\infty}\int_x^{x+h}f'(y)dy = 0$ for all $h>0$. I need to check if it is true or false that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_x^{x+h}f'(y)dy = 0$ for all $h>0$. Any hint will be welcome.

Comment: Is $f'\in L^1[0,\infty)?$ Or do we just have $f'\in L^1[0,r]$ for all $r>0.$

Comment: @zhw. Only $f'\in L^1[0,r]$ for all $r>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch: Choose $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $2^n +n^2+n < 2^{n+1}$ for $n\ge N.$ Define

$$g = \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\left ( \frac{1}{n}\chi_{(2^n,2^n+n^2)} - \chi_{(2^n+n^2,2^n+n^2+n)}\right ).$$

Now define $f(x) = \int_0^x g.$ Then $f$ is a counterexample. I'll leave it here for now. Ask if you have questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your example is clear.

Comment: I posted new question that is related to this one. You may have a glimpse of that.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2454100/does-limsup-x-to-inftyfxh-fx-0-and-liminf-x-to-inftyfxh-f

Answer (score 0):

... only if the second limit exists.  What's the infimum limit doing?  (This should be easy to determine.  Replace $f$ with $-f$ in your first argument.)  If the supremum and infimum limits agree, then the limit exists and agrees with them.