# $\limsup\limits_{x\to\infty}(f(x+h)-f(x)) = 0$ and $\liminf\limits_{x\to\infty}(f(x+h)-f(x)e^{-h})\ge0 \implies\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x+h)-f(x))= 0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I have an absolutely continuous function $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ that satisfies $$\limsup_{x\to\infty}(f(x+h)-f(x)) = 0$$ and $$\liminf_{x\to\infty}(f(x+h)-f(x)e^{-h})\ge0$$ for all $h>0$.

I need to check if it is true or false that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x+h)-f(x)) = 0$$ for all $h>0$. zhw. proved that the conjecture is false with only$$\limsup_{x\to\infty}(f(x+h)-f(x)) = 0$$ $\forall h>0$, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2450481/does-limsup-x-to-infty-int-xxhfydy-0-forall-h0-imply-lim). I am wondering that if it is true with the additional condition $$\liminf_{x\to\infty}(f(x+h)-f(x)e^{-h}) \ge0$$ $\forall h>0$. Any hint will be welcome.

Comment: What is your variables of integration?

Comment: @GuyFsone There is no integration. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Can you please go over your parentheses in the lines containing $e^{-h}$? It is unclear what multiplies what.

Comment: @uniquesolution Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The conjecture is false. The counter example is as follows:

Define $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ as $f(x) = e^{-1}$ if $x\in[0,1)\cup [n^2+n+1,(n+1)^2)$, $f(x) = e^{-1} + (1-e^{-1})(x-n^2)/n$ if $x\in [n^2,n^2+n)$, and $f(x) = e^{-(x-n^2-n)}$ if $x\in[n^2+n,n^2+n+1)$ for $n=1,2,\dots$. Then, $\limsup_{x\to\infty}(f(x+h)-f(x)) = 0$ and $\liminf_{x\to\infty}(f(x+h)-f(x)e^{-h})\ge 0$ for all $h>0$. On the other hand, $\liminf_{x\to\infty}(f(x+1)-f(x)) = e^{-1}-1<0$.